# How to define my own configuration in gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

In gradle plugin I wrote

```
project.configurations.create("myConf")
```

But when I import my plugin into project and write `myConf("smth:smth:smth")` the compiler doesn't recognize `myConf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the project with that plugin couldn't resolve my custom configuration at compile time.
I had to declare a variable `val myConf = configurations.getByName("myConf")` and then I could use it